# Need general directions to the idea for 'Bookshelf' app - table or scroll?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm currently stack at creating an app.
Our requirement is to make "book viewer" app similar to the iBooks. Each of the book is just series of images (JPEG or PNG) and not a pdf. So it's more like an image viewer in a sense.

The main view is going to be like "horizontal tableview", which the user can scroll horizontally the covers of the books, click it to download and open the book (which led to another page view). The row for the cover should be at least two since there's two "type" is set for the books. This part is more like a "pulse-style" bookshelf with UI similar to [this](http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/creating-pulse-style-scrolling-horizontally-scrolling-uitableview-as-a-subview-of-uitableviewcell/).

When I thought of how to implement this behaviour, I found the way with UITableView just as described [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1). However, as an objective-c beginner, it's little complicated for me to use this, and our requirement has also each "cell" must have multiple buttons to set each book as "favourite" or "downloaded" etc... and this could be more complicated if I choose to use the UITableView.

So I came to think of using UIScrollView to line up the book covers, embedding each cover as an UIImageView with buttons. But I really don't know if this is the right direction, sicne the UIScrollView has no "reload" function, and the requirement also stated that the user should be able to find the books by using "search bar" at the head of the bookshelf view.

As you can see, I'm completely confused and depressed because I don't know how can I achieve this. I searched around google and several answers here at stackoverflow suggest using [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView) or [EasyTableView](https://github.com/alekseyn/EasyTableView). They are both great, but again too complicated to implement these into our requirement...

Which way, or how should I implement this dynamic "pulse-style" bookshelf like feature?

I think my question is a bit vague, but I'm also not clear what to ask here because I really don't know how to do this. The Android version of this app is already achieved this requirement with fairly simple and easy to understand codes (since I have some experience in Java), but for this Objective-C, everything seem needlessly complicated...

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<preachy>`The fact is that you have made a mistake by trying to make this app with a complex interface full of non-standard UI components when you are “an objective-c beginner”.  I understand that this may not have been your decision; it may have been forced on you by the guy that signs your paychecks.  Nevertheless, it is not reasonable to expect that you can just implement this app before you've spent the time working through tutorials and reading documentation for the programming language and libraries required to build it.  We all have to learn the alphabet before we can start writing limericks.`</preachy>`

That said, if your app can require iOS 6, and you can take the time to learn a bit of Objective-C and iOS programming, it sounds like this would be pretty easy using `UICollectionView`.  Apple did a couple of sessions about this powerful new class at WWDC 2012.  I recommend you watch the videos:

- [Session 205 - Introducing Collection Views](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=205)
- [Session 219 - Advanced Collection Views and Building Custom Layouts](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=219)

You can also easily find some tutorials about `UICollectionView` using your favorite search engine.

Comment: Yes, you are right. And I understand that this is a complete mistake (and mess) that an objective-c "beginner" like me are forced to finish this job. I really need more time to spent learning this, but I guess it's not my boss' option. And I was really desperate to find a solution to this problem. Sadly, our requirement also specifies that we should also support iOS5, so I couldn't even consider the UICollectionView. I really wish if I could do this... Thanks anyway rob!

Comment: Take a look at [`PSTCollectionView`](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView).  It's not complete (last time I checked, anyway), but might be sufficient for you.

Comment: Thank you, rob! I will check it out right away. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Collection View's](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

You can even download some [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CollectionView-Simple/Introduction/Intro.html) to see how a grid layout can be accomplished.

Comment: Thanks Adam! But as I wrote to rob, we cannot use Collection Views... Thanks anyway for taking time to look at my question!